# VSCode not finding MOCK_METHOD from gmock in ROS unit tests

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, ros, googlemock

I'm trying to mock a particular class for a ROS (kinetic) unit test with gMock. I can get the unit tests to run as is using gTest but I'm getting errors in VSCode when trying to mock functions.

In my test file I have,

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

class Handlers
{
public:
    virtual bool onShutdown(void) { return true; };
    virtual bool onHardRestart(void) { return true; };
    virtual bool onSoftRestart(void) { return true; };
    virtual ~Handlers(){};
};

class MockHandlers : public Handlers
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, onShutdown, (void), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, onHardRestart, (void), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD(bool, onSoftRestart, (void), (override));
};
```

But the references to `MOCK_METHOD` have red squiggles underneath.

```
int MockHandlers::MOCK_METHOD(bool, <error-type>, <error-type>, <error-type>)
explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)
```

I'm assuming this is because the macro is being interpreted as a function declaration because MOCK_METHOD cannot be found. However, I can control+click through the `#include <gmock/gmock.h>` line with no problems which seems to say that the include paths are somewhat configured?

Running on Ubuntu 16.04 in VSCode with the following `c_cpp_properties.json`.

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "browse": {
        "databaseFilename": "",
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
      },
      "includePath": [
        "/home/alexytsu/Develop/catkin_ws/devel/include/**",
        "/opt/ros/kinetic/include/**",
        ... ${omitted my user-specific catkin_ws folders}
        "/usr/include/**"
      ],
      "name": "ROS",
      "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
      "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
      "cStandard": "c11"
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where's gmock lib installed? Are you sure you're using gmock 1.10? In previous versions, there was no `MOCK_METHOD` macro, but a separate macro depending on number of the mocked funciton's signature (number of parameters and cv type qualifiers to be precise), i.e. in your case you need to use `MOCK_METHOD0`, try this:

```
class MockHandlers : public Handlers
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(onShutdown ,bool());
    MOCK_METHOD0(onHardRestart ,bool());
    MOCK_METHOD0(onSoftRestart ,bool());
};
```

AFAIK Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 do not have `1.10` in the APT repo, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue.  Our code used a specific version of `gtest` and `gmock`, and our builds were done in a Docker image which only contained the versions of third-party libraries from our repository; however, the machine I use for editing also had `cmake-extras` installed, which includes `gtest` and `gmock`.  Those versions are installed in `/usr/include/gtest` and `/usr/include/gmock`, and were being found by VSCode before the desired versions.

The solution was to place links for the desired versions in the `includePath` of the configuration in `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` **before the `${default}`**, so that they are found by VSCode before any version in a default include path:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            ...
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/refpack/common/3rdparty/googletest/googlemock/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}/refpack/common/3rdparty/googletest/googletest/include",
                "${default}"
            ],
            ...
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

[ We need the `${default}` entry to pick up the standard Linux headers that are common to my machine and the Docker image.  It would have been nice to tell VSCode to ignore certain paths from `/usr/include`, but I couldn't figure out a way to do that.  The option to exclude folders only seems to apply to folder/file searches, not to Intellisense. ]